# Issues while using IN operator in SOQL

Tags: soql, salesforce-id, externalid

I have a list of string,`reqNumber`, containing External Opportunity Id.

I want to pull all the `Opportunities` belonging to the external Id's in `reqNumber`.

Following is my SOQL query

```
 list<Opportunity> opportunityBucket = new list<Opportunity>([Select Id,Recruiter_Name__c from Opportunity where Recruiter_Name__c IN :reqNumber]);
```

However the query returns no rows. `reqNumber` is not empty and corresponding `Opportunities` are available in my SF instance.

Not sure what am I missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is Recruiter_Name__c a lookup to another object with external IDs? The way you have it, you need to use Salesforce IDs in reqNumber. Change your SOQL to use Recruiter_Name_*r.ExternalID*_c. Change ExternalID__c to the name of the field that you are looking for.